# Android Studio Javadoc Generation error: cannot find symbol R

Tags: java, android, javadoc

I am trying to generate javadocs for a larger android project - using android studios built-in "Tools > Generate JavaDoc". I have tried different scopes (my module, a custom scope containing only the java files I created, Project Files, ...) but everytime there is a class included which uses `import com.my-app.R;` or a generated class such as `SomeFragmentBinding` for ViewBinding, I get an

`error: cannot find symbol` from javadoc...

Apart from this problem the usual building and executing of the app is completely successful and works like a charm, although I get some some warnings regarding my database layout. Also I am using Hilt for Dependency Injection, but I don't really think that is related?

Now I am a complete noob using gradle and my attempts to configure the javadoc task myself have failed - and from what I have found online this should generally work out-of-the-box.

Comment: this isn't really a solution so I will not answer my own question, but it worked for a buddy of mine after he deinstalled and reinstalled Java completely (all his versions) and I suppose I could have tried that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. Here is how I solved it:

1. In your build.gradle file, add this line

   `implementation files(pathtosdk)`
2. Go to Tools -> Generate Javadocs. In the command line args, add this line

   `-sourcepath pathtosdk`

To find the pathtosdk;

- Change from Android to Project.
- Open up External Libraries
- Open up the directory that's named like "Android  "
- You should see an android.jar file
- Right click and copy the absolute path. That is your pathtosdk.